# How to train a model on 2D features of varying length?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of strings of characters. Each character has its own vector of features of length 22.

So for example:

String 1: `LAAGVGNIYADEALFR`

String 2: `APVSFLLESVER`

Each character in each string has the following vector of features.

```
AA                 M
SS3                C
SS8                C
ASA          178.972
HseU          4.5287
HseD         7.80071
CN           13.7988
Psi          147.413
Phi         -91.9785
Theta         114.81
Tau          175.495
P3C         0.999991
P3E      7.52701e-06
P3H      1.92849e-06
P8C         0.999994
P8S      3.92237e-09
P8T      1.08177e-06
P8H      4.76341e-07
P8G      1.01462e-07
P8I      8.74657e-20
P8E      4.67836e-06
P8B      6.26615e-08
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The feature vectors for all the characters have the same length, but the number of characters in each string varies.

So each string has a (n x 22) table of features, where n is the number of characters.

Each string has a single target value associated with it that I'm trying to train a model to predict.

It's also important to note that same characters don't have the same feature values since the values are relative to the character's position in the string.

How can I represent those tables of different dimensions in the form of same-size vectors to prepare this data for training?

I'm using python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **zero paddings**. Add zero pads to both ends of the sequence until it reaches the specified maximum length.
If you're using PyTorch, use [torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html). If Tensorflow, use [tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences).